# As vehicle speed increases does the amount of friction decrease?

Tags: friction

To further clarify... I'm attempting to figure out whether friction is reduced the faster a vehicle moves. It's easy to understand that faster vehicles take more time and distance to stop.

Comment: Is there a velocity term included in the friction equation, I would look at that:   http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class deals with this

Comment: Do you just mean friction due to surface to surface contacts, or do you want to consider resistances like air drag?

Answer (score 0):

No  you overcome friction to a greater  extent  if  you  move  fast ..
The faster  you move , the net force  in the  direction you're moving increases ..
Since  the  force  is  very large  in magnitude  ..
The vehicle  takes a  longer  time  to Decelerate ..
So comes  to rest  after a  relatively  longer  period of  time .